# How to make 6 calculation as fast as possible based on one datastream?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I have one stream of data who is coming very fast, and when a new data arrive, I would like to make 6 different calculation based on it.
I would like to make those calculation as fast as possible so I can update as soon as I receive new data.
The data can arrive as fast as milliseconds so my calculation must be very fast.

So the best thing I was thinking of was to make those calculations on 6 different Threads at the same time.

I never used threads before so I don't know where to place it.

This is the code who describe my problem

What can I do from here?

```
import numpy as np

import time

np.random.seed(0)

def calculation_1(data, multiplicator):
    r = np.log(data * (multiplicator+1))
    return r

start = time.time()
for ii in range(1000000):
    data_stream_main = [np.random.uniform(0, 2.0), np.random.uniform(10, 1000.0), np.random.uniform(0, 0.01)]

    # calculation that has to be done together
    calc_1 = calculation_1(data=data_stream_main[0], multiplicator=2)
    calc_2 = calculation_1(data=data_stream_main[0], multiplicator=3)

    calc_3 = calculation_1(data=data_stream_main[1], multiplicator=2)
    calc_4 = calculation_1(data=data_stream_main[1], multiplicator=3)

    calc_5 = calculation_1(data=data_stream_main[2], multiplicator=2)
    calc_6 = calculation_1(data=data_stream_main[2], multiplicator=3)

print(calc_1)
print(calc_2)
print(calc_3)
print(calc_4)
print(calc_5)
print(calc_6)

print("total time:", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Note that threads in Python are for *concurrency*, not *parallelism*. Threads will help speed up I/O bound code, not CPU bound code. Even with proper parallelism, you would have to account for overhead to branch out and back in – that is rarely useful for micro-tasks on the scale of microseconds. If speed is your issue, straight up increasing the single-thread performance via compilation (e.g. via PyPy, Cython, Numba, Nuitka, ...) is a much better fit.

Comment: You mean that the order of the calculation will be random but it will never perform two calculation at the same time?

Comment: In simple terms, yes. Threads are restricted by the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) so that only one thread can execute/access Python functions/objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either class `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to create a multiprocessing pool of 6 processes to which you can submit your 6 tasks in your loop to execute in parallel and await the results. The following example uses `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`.

**But, the result will be very disappointing.**

The problem is that (1) There is overhead in initially creating the 6 processes and (2) overhead in queueing up each task to execute in the different address space that the subprocesses live. This means that for multiprocessing to be advantageous, your worker function, `calculation_1` in this case, needs to be a less-trivial, longer-running, more-CPU-intensive function. If you were to add to your worker function the following "do-nothing", CPU-intensive loop ...

```py
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        cnt += 1
```

... then the following multiprocessing code *would* run several times more quickly. As is, stick with what you have.

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def calculation_1(data, multiplicator):
    r = np.log(data * (multiplicator+1))
    """
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        cnt += 1
    """
    return r

# required for Windows and other platforms that use spawn for creating new processes:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(0)
    # no point in using more processes than processors:
    n_processors = min(6, mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(n_processors)
    start = time.time()
    for ii in range(1000000):
        data_stream_main = [np.random.uniform(0, 2.0), np.random.uniform(10, 1000.0), np.random.uniform(0, 0.01)]
        # calculation that has to be done together
        # submit tasks:
        result_1 = pool.apply_async(calculation_1, (data_stream_main[0], 2))
        result_2 = pool.apply_async(calculation_1, (data_stream_main[0], 3))
        result_3 = pool.apply_async(calculation_1, (data_stream_main[1], 2))
        result_4 = pool.apply_async(calculation_1, (data_stream_main[1], 3))
        result_5 = pool.apply_async(calculation_1, (data_stream_main[2], 2))
        result_6 = pool.apply_async(calculation_1, (data_stream_main[2], 3))

        # wait for results:
        calc_1 = result_1.get()
        calc_2 = result_2.get()
        calc_3 = result_3.get()
        calc_4 = result_4.get()
        calc_5 = result_5.get()
        calc_6 = result_6.get()

    print(calc_1)
    print(calc_2)
    print(calc_3)
    print(calc_4)
    print(calc_5)
    print(calc_6)

    print("total time:", time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could factorize the calculation by separating the `log(data)` from the `log(multiplicator)`.

Given that `np.log(data * (multiplicator+1))` is the same as `np.log(data) + np.log(multiplicator+1)`, you can compute and store the 2 possible values of `np.log(multiplicator+1)` in global variables,  then only compute `log(data)` once per index (thus saving 50%) on that part.

```
# global variables and calculation function:
multiplicator2 = np.log(3)
multiplicator3 = np.log(4)
def calculation_1(data):
    logData = np.log(data)
    return logData + multiplicator2, logData + multiplicator3 


#  in the loop:...

    calc_1,calc_2 = calculation_1(data_stream_main[0])
    calc_3,calc_4 = calculation_1(data_stream_main[1])
    calc_5,calc_6 = calculation_1(data_stream_main[2])
```

If you can afford to buffer several rows of data into a numpy matrix before outputing the result, you may get some performance improvement by using numpy's parallelism to perform the calculation on the whole matrix (or chunk) and output the result in chunks instead of one row at a time.  Separating reception of the data from computation and output is where the use of threads may provide a benefit.

For example:

```
start = time.time()
chunk = []
multiplicators = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3])
for ii in range(1000000):
    data_stream_main = [np.random.uniform(0, 2.0), np.random.uniform(10, 1000.0), np.random.uniform(0, 0.01)]
    chunk.append(data_stream_main*2)
    if len(chunk)< 1000: continue
    # process 1000 lines at a time and output results
    calcs = np.log(np.array(chunk)*multiplicators)
    calc_1,calc_4,calc_2,calc_5,calc_3,calc6 = calcs[-1,:]
    chunk = [] # reset chunk
    
print("total time:", time.time() - start) # 2.7 (compared to 6.6)
```